# Fail xUnit tests with Moq in tfs

Tags: tfs, moq, xunit, castle

I have three test that wrote using Xunit 2.3.0 and I mocked some services using Moq 4.7.137 that is used Castle.Core 4.2.0 .
My tests work correctly in my local workspace but in Team Foundation Server 2015 they fail with following error :

```
2017-10-10T08:20:44.7293310Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8448542]       System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7293310Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8457824]       ---- System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Boolean Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyUtil.IsAccessible(System.Reflection.MethodBase, System.String ByRef)'.

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7293310Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8466110]       ---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: LoanFixture fixture

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7449508Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8598342]       Stack Trace:

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7449508Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8607783]         

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7449508Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8615987]         ----- Inner Stack Trace #1 (System.MissingMethodException) -----

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7449508Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8624251]            at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.IsMethodVisible(MethodInfo method, String& messageIfNotVisible)

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7605671Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8632101]         C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs(811,0): at Moq.Mock.ThrowIfSetupMethodNotVisibleToProxyFactory(MethodInfo method)

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7605671Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8640470]         C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs(439,0): at Moq.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass62_0`1.<Setup>b__0()

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7605671Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8648863]         C:\projects\moq4\Source\PexProtector.cs(61,0): at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke[T](Func`1 function)

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7605671Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8656833]         C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs(432,0): at Moq.Mock.Setup[T](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Condition condition)

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7605671Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8664444]         C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.Generic.cs(263,0): at Moq.Mock`1.Setup(Expression`1 expression)

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7605671Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8672662]         s\Banking\Banking.LoanManagement.Domain.Tests\Core\LoanFixture.cs(98,0): at Banking.LoanManagement.Domain.Tests.Core.LoanFixture.Initialize()

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7605671Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8680978]         s\Banking\Banking.LoanManagement.Domain.Tests\Core\LoanFixture.cs(36,0): at Banking.LoanManagement.Domain.Tests.Core.LoanFixture..ctor()

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7605671Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8688788]         ----- Inner Stack Trace #2 (Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException) -----

2017-10-10T08:20:44.7605671Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:22.8696267]
```

I have checkedin all releated packages .
I also set test runner on tfs test task . but I can not solve this

Comment: Did you do the same environment settings as your " local workspace" on the build agent machine? If not, just try that. That means deploy the build agent environment same as your develop machine which works no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question and I forgot to answer that. In this case, the problem was related to specflow bug in the previous version and then it is fixed.